# Is windows 10 WebView will use Microsoft Edge (Chromium) going forward

Tags: uwp, microsoft-edge, progressive-web-apps, chromium

UWP WebView is using EdgeHTML to render content. will this be replaced with Microsoft Edge (Chromium) with 20H1 release?

We are building a PWA app, which is going to host under WebView control in UWP app. We want to know, if this application continue run on EdgeHTML?

Comment: I'm in favor of Johnny's answer. The WebView2 control is currently in developer preview. We need to install WebView2 SDK if we want to use it in the app. You could refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/gettingstarted) for the usage of WebView2 (developer preview). So if you don't install WebView2 SDK, you're still using WebView EdgeHTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in WebView will still continue to use EdgeHTML for stability and consistency reasons.

WebView2, currently in preview ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2 ) is an external library you may add to your application to render using Edge Chromium instead.

So unless you explicitly add WebView2 to your code, your PWA should continue to use EdgeHTML (unless your PWA is built on a third party framework, in which case it's up to the whims of the framework developer in which direction they go in the future).

Comment: Thank You Johnny for guidance. I am currently not able to use PWA notification using webview control. The control does not show notification permission popup.  Do you know, how we can obtain user permission for notification using webview.